# How to remove an asset from a particular view in yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

i have a view called `reports` where i want to show a bootstrap dropdown.

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
  <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

It is not working only in this view. I found out that in this view there is multiple bootstrap js files.

```
<script src="/~folder/project/web/theme/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/~folder/project/web/assets/db70fa5c/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

How can i remove one among these?

I tried creating a new RegisterAsset.php file where i left out the script

```
<script src="/~folder/project/web/theme/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

but still it is being seen in the view. What should i do?

Comment: How about making a new layout without the assets that aren't required?

Comment: new layout for a single view page? @WeSee

Comment: Yes, since assets are registered in layouts usually.

Comment: can't i register an asset for a particular view? @WeSee

Comment: Of course. But avoiding to register standard assets from Bootstrap in a single view is not possible.

Comment: ok thanks @WeSee. I tried as u said and it is working

Comment: As far as I can tell assets are evil! At least in Yii2 FW... I am trying to write an single page app using Yii2 and because of that automagic assetBundle crap that was nearly impossible. Lost too much time on this framework. If anybody is planning to write an app with complex UI should consider different framework or different approach. For example RESTful service written in Yii2 (that is done very nicely) + some frontend JS framework like AngularJS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Problem analysis

If everything was specified properly this wouldn't be possible. Yii2 would detect that you are registering the same asset twice and only include it once. In your example the second one (not the minified one) seems registered the right way, while the first one gets registered from a theme folder.

It looks like you are using an extension or some theme which uses its own asset-file (and its own bootstrap file!) being registered from a non-asset folder (`web/theme/...`). Not really according to the specifications... ;)

#### Let's solve it!

Find out which asset is registering your second bootstrap-file (the onein the theme folder). Now you can simply override the config of this asset via your global config-file. To do so first read the [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html#asset-mapping) and then do the following in your `config/web.php`:

```
'assetManager'=>[
    //...
    'bundles'=>[
        'namespace\to\your\failing\asset\Bundle'=>[
            //add all css-files of the bundle except the duplicate one here
            'js'=>['js/fileA.js', 'js/fileB.js'],
        ],
    ],
    //...
],
```

Now you specify the js-files of the bundle except the one which is duplicate. This does now override the asset-config for this bundle and should therefore solve your problem without excluding something from within the views (which would be against the basic idea of the asset management).

Finding the failing asset bundle should be easy. Simply look for a class in your theme extending `yii\web\AssetBundle` and having the file `bootstrap.min.js` in its `$js`-array.